# passing file (or parameters) that choose from java file to vbscript

Tags: java, user-interface, vbscript, swingx

I built GUI in java , that the user can load files from it.
now i want to pass those file to script that already exists , but the script until now let the user to choose file in the script and i want to prevent that and pass the file directly from the java GUI.
is it possible?

for example:

```
if(click.getSource() == chooseLog){
            JFileChooser fc3 = new JFileChooser();
            if(fc3.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                LOG = fc3.getSelectedFile();
                fc3Bol = true;
}
}

if(click.getSource() == analayze){
   if(fc3Bol == true){
                // here i want to start vbscript that will get the LOG file
                }
 }
```

Comment: Modify the script to accept file names as a command line

Comment: can you give your example?

Comment: if i want to get the LOG path into variable in the vbscript?

Comment: `WshArguments` Object is a collection returned by the WScript object's _Arguments_ property (`WScript.Arguments`). Read [VBScript command line arguments](http://ss64.com/vb/syntax-args.html)